# C# performance for integer variables

Tags: c#, performance, integer, generic-list

I know already that it is recommended to use int variables in for loop Just curios about performance it is recommended to use other integral types other than int C# and when ?

The real purpose of this question is that I have to create a generic List of type T where T is a structure that contains fields of type string and integer. So I think that optimizing the structure will have an immediate impact on optimization on the whole list

I suspect that my lists will be so long ...

Thanks

Comment: Well what is the integer value meant to represent? Is your structure *definitely* appropriate to be a structure in the first place?

Comment: what the integr represent have no link to the answer : some integers are elligebile to have the type ushort and others the type byte  I am just wondering if not giving them all the same length 32 bits will agffect performance

Comment: **This is a waste of your development time.** Leave the structure unoptimized and come back if you have a *measurable* performance problem.

Comment: @Oumdaa: No, the meaning of the variable *absolutely* changes which type you should use - because in almost all cases you should focus on the *clearest* type to represent the data involved. Measure the performance and see if it's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I must be less sensitive to performance things

I just review my needs and dicscover that changing types will save me as maximum 24*N*bits where N is the length of list N~10K so ~240kbits that's no big deal at all !

Answer (score 3):

(The usual premature optimization warnings apply to this answer. I'll assume that you really need maximum performance.)

Optimizing classes and structs for size by use of the smallest feasible type is a valid optimization. In your case, you won't gain anything because the two structs `string,int` and `string,byte` would have the same size due to padding.

In general, this technique is valid though. You save on memory usage and gain on locality of reference, cache usage and reduced memory bandwidth.

Changing the loop counter variable to a smaller type does not gain anything because any operation on an integer smaller than `int` widens back to int.

Comment: As I said my list will be long. Please could you explain more how the structures string,int and string,byte  will have the same size ?

Comment: @Oumdaa structs are *packed* on the CLR. The data size of a struct is rounded up to the nearest multiple of 4 or 8 (depending on if you are running as 32 or 64 bit). So if you reduce data size from 12 to 9 you still have a struct size of 12.

Comment: OK, thanks very much; May be I must be less sensitive to performance things I just review my needs and dicscover that changing types will save me as maximum 24*N*bits where N is the length of list N~1K so ~24kbits that's no big deal at all !